# Stampede: How does this custom spell compare to Cloudkill, another 5th level spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, homebrew-review

Is this *stampede* spell (a proposed custom spell for Druids and Rangers in my upcoming campaign) as strong as, or weaker than, the 5th level spell *cloudkill*?  I used a similar base damage, the duration is reduced from 10 minutes to 1 minute, and the "persistent" effect of the poison is replaced by a chance to be trampled if knocked prone.  I reduced the directional control somewhat.

> **Stampede**
> Spell level 5 (conjuration)
> Casting Time: 1 action
> Range: 120 feet
> Components: V, S Duration: Concentration, up to 1 minute
>
> You create a 40' wide, 20'deep, line of spiritual herd animals<sup>1</sup> (buffalo, horses, giraffes, zebras, etc) at a point you choose within range.  The animals stampede in the direction that you choose and will continue in that direction until either the spell ends or you cease concentration on it.  The stampede moves at a speed of 40'.
> **Effects on Creatures**
> Any **creature** in the spell’s area of effect on the caster's turn takes 5d8 bludgeoning damage on a failed Dexterity saving throw, and is knocked
> prone.  On a successful save, the creature takes half damage and is not knocked prone. Any **creature** knocked prone takes an additional 2d4+3 bludgeoning<sup>2</sup> damage if the saving throw result was 11 or lower<sup>3</sup>.
> **Effects on Objects**
> **Objects** that are not held or worn by creatures in the path of the stampede take 5d8 bludgeoning damage.  Objects of size Large, or larger, that are not destroyed by the bludgeoning damage cause the stampede to flow around the object.  Any creature caught in the area of that flow around an object takes half damage on a failed Dexterity saving throw, and one quarter damage on a successful one.
> **Effects of Terrain on the Spell**
> The herd will plunge through rivers, go over cliffs, or try to flow around a cliff base's face (likewise with castle walls that are not knocked down, gigantic rock outcroppings, etc).   Difficult terrain will not reduce the speed of the stampede.  This spell can be used underwater, and will manifest as herds of spiritual giant sea horses, schools of large fish, etc.
>
> **At Higher Levels**. When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 6th
> level or higher, the damage increases by 1d8 for each slot level above
> 5th.

---

In trying to get the flavor right, I am not sure if the relative power level of the spell is retained at 5th level.  **Is this comparably powered to cloudkill at 5th level?**

---

<sup>1</sup> These herd animals are similar to what is summoned by *spirit guardians*, rather than creatures that are summoned by the *conjure animals* (Druid, level 3)(Response to @MikeQ).  There isn't a stat block for a *herd* in the way that there is for a *swarm*.

<sup>2</sup> This is based on MM/PHB riding horse hoof damage.

<sup>3</sup> The fiddly bit was intended to avoid making two saving throws; one roll covers it all. Some spells do have multiple save chances, so an alternative would be that the second (Constitution or Dexterity) to avoid trample damage. I modeled this after the Sprite's "if the saving throw result is X or lower, it puts them them to sleep" ability.

Comment: On the scale of pure-RP to pure-Strategy, where does your table stands? I'm not sure it changes much in the answer to your question, but I feel like it changes the level of analysis you're looking for. (As well as possibly how the spell might be used)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77814/discussion-between-v2blast-and-korvinstarmast).

Comment: @3C273 I'd say about 50-50, and most of our sessions have a significant "beer and pretzels" feel to them.  (For example, my brother (DM) gave my cleric a free cantrip "bless the beer" ... no mechanical value except in one or two RP sessions where an NPC appreciated blessed beer ...

Comment: Any section that requires two footnotes to explain is probably too fiddly to exist in the first place. I would drop the added damage just to reduce the complexity. It isn't a major change in the spell's power, so the accepted answer's analysis is still valid.

Comment: @TJL As we have not gotten to play test it yet (the druid PC never materialized) I can make that change ... thatnks for your insights.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Would a caster be able to use this for *underwater combat*, too? I thought of just changing the flavour a bit to giant seahorses, a school of tuna, or a group of leatherback turtles, or something similar.

Comment: @Thank-Glob Yes, it can, so should I add that to the terrain effects?

Comment: @kirt hmm, good points.  How does that edit look.  Do I have to specify that boulders, trees, etc are not treated as objects?  Hmm.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast  Grammar nitpick: "Objects that are not held or worn in the path of the stampede" could be "Objects in the path of the stampede that are not held or worn by creatures take..."  I don't think it is necessary to specify that terrain like trees and boulders are not objects - if a DM wants to treat them as terrain, that's fine, but if they would prefer have the stampede damage them, that's fine too.  Would the spell cast underwater summon water buffalos?  ;)

Comment: @Kirt Thanks, I'll fix that too. Appreciate the help.

Comment: +1 Thanks for adding underwater to the terrain. It is a great 5th-level spell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## It is ok for level 5

Let's compare all aspects of the spells

### Damage type

Poison is the [worst](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/103214/9552), while magical bludgeoning is the best.
Stampede wins by a large margin.

### Range

Same initially, Stampede can reach much further in the end.
Stampede wins.

### Area and damage

These are hard to separate.
Stampede does more damage per round, if the target falls prone, but it can only damage an enemy multiple times *if it runs in the direction the charging animals do, and about the same speed*, meaning away from you. If they are running away, you already won.
Cloudkill moves much slower, a stationary enemy will remain in the area for several rounds.
Cloudkill wins by a very large margin against most enemies.

### Duration

Most encounters do not reach the fifth round, and on average are about [3 rounds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/93185/9552). So both will last the whole combat.

In my experience combat encounters are mostly further apart in time than 10 minutes, closer to 60. If they are more frequent, it usually happens because the party is running somewhere. These two together mean that area spells most of the time last a single encounter, regardless of duration.

## About as good as Cloudkill

Unless I know that the *Second Goblin Army* is coming, I will prepare Cloudkill. It has a horrible damage type, but I will simply use something else against undead and elementals.
But at least it has a quite good chance to damage my enemies more than once.

Comment: After a second read through, nice answer covering all of my concerns.  Thank you.

Comment: Where is this sudden interest coming from, 3 years later on a niche spell?

Comment: Someone found it, popped an up vote, I came back and realized I needed to clean up some of the prose (didn't reflect how spells are written) and the edit moved it to the front page.  I also then chose to C&P to get some feedback from the GiTP Homebrew forum.  Your answer is still solid and was very helpful to me.  The party I DM for on wednesday's is likely to run into this spell in a few sessions, perhaps in a few days. Thanks again for your answer back when you wrote it.